# AWS Cloudformation Parameters - How to make Subnet options available based on VPC

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I'm creating an EMR Cluster cloudformation template which will be used to create EMRs in different regions. 
Since it's for multiple regions, I'm passing the vpc and subnet options as parameters so that we can choose the relevant during stack creation.

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: Choose the VPC for this EMR
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

  Subnet:
    Description: Choose the subnet for this EMR
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  KeyName:
    Description: Choose the keypair to login
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
```

When I create the stack with this template, CF shows all the VPCs available in the region and all the subnets in available VPCs. How to modify it so that Subnet dropdown shows only the subnets available in the VPC we choose?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Unfortunately not even by using lambda and custom attribute, because data for dropdowns are collected before select form is shown to user.